# Use of file path from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem. When I add new element to my bullet list:

```
<input id="wejscie" type="file" accept="video/*"/>
<ol id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4">Happy Fit</li>
    <li movieurl="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4">Sintel</li>          
    <li movieurl="http://html5example.net/static/video/html5_Video_VP8.webm">Resident Evil</li>      
    <li movieurl="http://www.ioncannon.net/examples/vp8-webm/big_buck_bunny_480p.webm">Big Buck    Bunny</li>
</ol>
```

with this function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#wejscie").on("change", function() {
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
        var file = this.files[0];
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        var fileName = '';
        function getName(s) {
            return s.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        }
        fileName = getName(fileURL);
        $("ol").append('<li movieurl="' + fileURL + '">' + fileName + '</li>'); 
    });
});
```

when I switch video to one from default and back to added it will not play.
To play video I use this function:

```
$(function() {
            $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
                $("#videoarea").attr({
                    "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
                    "poster": "",
                    "autoplay": "autoplay"
                });
            });
            $("#videoarea").attr({
                "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
                "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
            });
        });
```

Also my fileName is just bunch of random letters and numbers. Can You tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong with the file name. For security reasons browsers don't allow the actual name or path of the file to be obtained through javascript.

Comment: So is there any option to play the video with saved fileURL under <li movieurl> after click?

Comment: You need to upload it to the server, retrieve it and then play it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this problem you're having is because the videos you add with the file input are not bound to the click event handler. You need to delegate this listener. I've made a few changes to the code that you had but the main one is `$("#playlist").on("click", "li", function () {` to make sure that the `li`s that you add dynamically still have the click event listening. I've added a demo that works also.

**UPDATE:** I've updated the code so when an `li` is clicked the `#videoarea` gets a `.data` of the index of which `li` was clicked. After that, I've added a `ended` event listener on `#videoarea`. Now when the video is done playing it it will get the `li` of the video that just finished, then grab the `.next` `li`, then trigger a `click` of that next `li`.

```
$("#wejscie").on("change", function () {
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
        file = this.files[0],
        fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file),
        fileName = file.name.replace(/^.*\//ig, '');

    $("ol").append('<li movieurl="' + fileURL + '">' + fileName + '</li>');
});


$("#playlist").on("click", "li", function () {
    var i = $('#playlist li').index(this);

    $("#videoarea").data('i', i).attr({
        "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": "",
        "autoplay": "autoplay"
    });
});

$("#videoarea").on('ended', function(){
    var i = $(this).data('i'),
        $nextvid = $('#playlist li:eq('+i+')').next();

    if(!!$nextvid.length){
        $nextvid.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bpr38/1/)

Comment: Thanks! Maybe You know also how to make to play next video automatically after end of previous video?:)

Comment: @KorWojci let me do a little research and get back to you

Comment: @KorWojci I've updated my answer to achieve what you wanted in the comment.